# How to connection to an IIS website using Kerberos

Tags: asp.net, iis, kerberos

When i connect to one of our internal website and i look in the event viewer security tab I can see that the Authentication Package is NTLM

What do i need to do so that the Authentication Package is kerberos?

The website is an ASP.NET website with IIS 6 and uses windows authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, IIS 6 will try and use Kerberos to authenticate the client if it is available. [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/215383) is a good article you may want to check out. It has steps to view/edit what you have enabled.